# Please pause the timer when hovering question in "Realtime Questions" on Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, realtime-questions

There is cool [realtime questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime) tab on Stack Exchange portal, showing questions as they're being asked or modified. So far so good.

There is a timer running **live** (got much worse, used to be every 10 seconds in the past) that will update the list, adding new questions on top and pushing all the rest down.

Suppose I saw something interesting and I want to click it - I'm not quick enough and while I'm hovering it ready to click, the timer is executed and push it downwards. Fail. Now it's a game of "catch me if you can" which might be fun... or not.

Can the timer please be paused while we're hovering the list of questions, at least for a certain amount of time? (in case we just leave the mouse there by mistake)

Another option is adding a pause icon:

> [image: realtime questions tab with pause icon]

Comment: yeah, that would be could. currently you need some luck to hit the right question

Comment: It's a websocket feed, not a timer :)

Comment: @ArtOfCode *blush*... oh, maybe they changed it over those four years? Pretty sure it was much slower. (i.e. actual timer, but didn't bother to really check the code or network tab.)

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard Smokey uses the same websocket that feeds that page, so I _hope_ it's still a websocket ;)

Comment: @ArtOfCode meant it used to be old fashioned timer and AJAX on SE.com page, then at some point they changed it to use the websocket. (maybe)